# c# System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException error and can't find an anwser

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a programming error in one of my C# projects. Now I'm already trying to get it out for a couple of days but can't find the problem. For some reason I keep getting an "System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException" on this line of code:

```
var userData = user.SingleOrDefault();
```

but I don't know why or what the problem is.

This is my code:

```
private void updateChat()
{
    var query = from gp_chat in DB.gp_chat 
                where gp_chat.user_id != Program.userID 
                select gp_chat;

   // Check if exits
   if (query != null)
   {
       foreach (var data in query)
       {
           // Add records
           if (Convert.ToInt64(data.time) > timeUpdated)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(data.user_id);
               var user = from gp_accounts in DB.gp_accounts 
                          where gp_accounts.id == data.user_id 
                          select gp_accounts;

               if (user != null)
               {
                   var userData = user.SingleOrDefault();
                   // Add records
                   lbxChat.Items.Add(/*UppercaseFirst(userData.username)*/ "test:" + ": " + data.message);
                   // Clear user
                   user = null;
                   //userData = null;
                   // Set time started
                   timeUpdated = Convert.ToInt64(GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now));
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger and inspect what the `user` object contains.  Does it have multiple records? Are there two users in the database with the same ID? The .SingleOrDefault method throws an exception if there are multiple matching elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser, i have look into it and there is only 1 result in de var userData, also in the database there are no same ids, its also a primary key. So it have to be something else.

Comment: What happens if you use `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: What's the inner exception?